# Using useState , how to set variable type to be optionally undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have this code

[image]

In my application `user` could be `undefined` (It later get set after api call). I want to set `user` type to be `UserRecord | undefined` . So that when I tried to get `userId` it should throw typescript warning/error that `user` could be `undefined`.

I tried this, but it doesn't work as expected.

[image]

My needs is that typescript should throw error when I try to access `._id` without checking `user` type yet. How I can define type?

Comment: It sounds like you might not have [strict null checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) turned on for typescript. Can you show us your tsconfig file?

Comment: @NicholasTower you are right. I set it and now work as expected. Please post as answer. I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because [strict null checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) are apparently not enabled. When that setting is not on, typescript basically ignores `null` and `undefined`. Once you turn it on, both of the lines of code you had screenshots of should work as expected.

You can turn on strict mode by adding this line to your `tsconfig` file:

```
"strict": true,
```

If for some reason you just want strictNullChecks, but not the rest of strict mode the following is also possible, though i'd recommend using the full strict mode:

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using TypeScript optional chaining operator(?).

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<UserRecord | undefined>();
const userId = user?._id;
```

Comment: I am expecting typescript to throw error. But it is not. So there is nothing to solve by `optional operator (?)`

Comment: Then, it could be a problem with your vscode environment.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in case of props I am getting on optional prop on children, and it helped me.

```
const [isDropdownOpen, setIsDropdownOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

and in the child, it assigned as

```
setIsDropdownOpen?.(false)
```